# How pods without any resource quota are handled by kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

How much cpu and memory resources are allocated to a pod if we do not apply any resource quota in kubernetes?
How they are changed when we scale up/down our deployment?
I tried reading kubernetes docs but was unable to find above answers.
I am using amazon-eks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you do not specify a memory limit for a Container, one of the
> following situations applies:
>
> - The Container has no upper bound on the amount of memory it uses. The
>   Container could use all of the memory available on the Node where
>   it is running.
> - The Container is running in a namespace that has a default memory limit, and the Container is automatically assigned the default limit.
>   Cluster administrators can use a LimitRange to specify a default value
>   for the memory limit.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/

> If you do not specify a CPU limit for a Container, then one of these
> situations applies:
>
> - The Container has no upper bound on the CPU resources it can use. The Container could use all of the CPU resources available on the Node
>   where it is running.
> - The Container is running in a namespace that has a default CPU limit, and the Container is automatically assigned the default limit.
>   Cluster administrators can use a LimitRange to specify a default value
>   for the CPU limit.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/